# How to remove the black and white bars from the top of my Minecraft client?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I am running a modded version of Minecraft on my computer, which is a Mac Mini running OSX. I have the latest update of Java 7 and I am running the FTB Unleashed v1.1.3 launcher and have not had issues in the past. I have reset both the launcher and the machine a few times and have had no success so far.

Here is a screenshot of my launcher:

[image]

Any help or advice would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Try resizing the game (this isn't your launcher btw). Then try giving it more ram. IIRC unleashed was really poorly optimized. DW20 1.6 fixed that though.

Comment: @Chipperyman Thanks for clarifying that the client is not the launcher. Resized the client while the bars were present, but the problem remained, but when I relaunched Unleashed they were gone. As I am new to FTB, I'm not sure what IIRC is, or DW20 for that matter, but that will give me something that I can research. Also, if you answer the question, I'll upvote and use it as the solution.

Comment: IIRC = If I remember correctly; DW20 = [Direwolf20 pack](http://ftbwiki.org/Direwolf20_1.6_Pack)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding my ram to the launcher. Click `options` at the top and drag the ram slider:

[image]

I believe unleashed *requires* at least 2.5GB ram to work properly and recommends at least 3. Don't drag it above 4, as it will mess with Java.

Also make sure you have [64-bit java](http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp) on a Windows computer (this does not matter on OSX).

I also suggest switching to the [Direwolf20 (DW20) 1.6.4 pack](http://ftbwiki.org/Direwolf20_1.6_Pack) as it uses a newer version of Minecraft, has updated mods and is slightly moer optimized.

Comment: I only use Unleashed because the server I play on uses it.